# Is this an emergency tool ie; seatbelt cutter/ glass breaker

Tags: glass

[image: What is this]
I think this is an emergency tool. Glass punch/seatbelt cutter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because houses don't have seatbelts. This site is for DIY Home Improvement; please take the [tour] and see the [help] for more information.

Answer (score 6):

That is not a glass break tool. It's a chip inserter.

[image]

You put the microchip in the U shaped slot at the bottom, then use the plunger at the top to push the chip in to the circuit board or holder.

Answer (score 0):

The image is a little blurry but it appears to be an auto emergency tool.  But usefulness of said tool appears to be lacking.  If you are frantic, do you really think you will have the patience to get the belt in that tiny cutter at the bottom.  Also the glass break seams to be more of a hammer head (flat) instead of the typical spiked.  And then if that tool was to slip as your were banging on the glass, would you cut yourself on the bottom?  I'm not even sure what those middle saw ridges are.  Yes it might be an auto emergency tool, but it also might be more useful in the trash.  It's up to you what you want to do with it.